# Can't update after Join added to query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, join

Normally I do a query like this

```
var Incentivo = _contexto.Incentivos.Where(x => x.EmpleadoID.Equals(ce) && x.mdEstatusRegistro)
```

Then I update table like this:

```
 Incentivo.nPorcentajeAJU = (ajuste / Incentivo.nSueldoActual) * 100;
 Incentivo.nSueldoNuevo = Incentivo.nSueldoActual + (Incentivo.nSueldoActual * Incentivo.nPorcentajeMAT) + (Incentivo.nSueldoActual * Incentivo.nPorcentajeAJU);
 Incentivo.mdFechaModificacion = f;
 Incentivo.mdUsuarioModificacion = Usuario;
 this._contexto.Entry(Incentivo).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

It works fine, but now I want to use `Join` in query like:

```
 var Incentivo = _contexto.Incentivos.Where(x => x.EmpleadoID.Equals(ce) && x.mdEstatusRegistro)
                 .Join(captura, x => x.CapturaID, y => y.ID, (x, y) => new { x, y });
```

But now update is unusefull I get:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'IQueryable<>' does not contain a definition for 'nPorcentajeAJU' and no extension method 'nPorcentajeAJU' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I get this message in each line of update
[image]

What I need to do to get it work? Regards

Comment: The error message you post is incomplete. Can you retrieve the complete message from the exception and post it here? Also can you tell which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: Exception is throw because all lines of update marked in red , when I put mouse over That lines I receive that error @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Can you share the complete error message which you see in the ErrorList window of Visual Studio? And also the line for which it shows the error?

Comment: I update me question with requested data @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Your `Join` query returns anonymous type that contains `Incentivos` and `Capturas` entities - not just `Incentivos`, so then when you're trying to use `nPorcentajeAJU` property it doesn't found on the anonymous type definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this error because you are not selecting correct entities after you JOIN `Incentivos` with `captura`.

The type of final output of the following query

```
var Incentivo = _contexto.Incentivos.Where(x => x.EmpleadoID.Equals(ce) && x.mdEstatusRegistro)
             .Join(captura, x => x.CapturaID, y => y.ID, (x, y) => new { x, y });
```

would be as following (I have put the types names just based on what I see in the question. They might be different in actual code).

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<JoinIterator>d__37`4[Incentivo ,System.String,<>f__AnonymousType0`2[Incentivo ,Captura]]
```

With the `IEnumerable` returned from the query it won't have the properties of `Incentivo` class. And that's why you are seeing the errors.

To solve this issue you need to select the object of `Incentivo` from the above collections.

So the final query should look like as following.

```
var Incentivo = _contexto.Incentivos.Where(x => x.EmpleadoID.Equals(ce) && x.mdEstatusRegistro)
             .Join(captura, x => x.CapturaID, y => y.ID, (x, y) => new { x, y }).Select(a => a.x).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will give you an object of `Incentivo` class and you can access properties like `nPorcentajeAJU` on it.

There are chance that `Incentivo` will be null if matching data does not exist in the database. In that case you better check if it is not null before trying to access its properties.

Following is an example code to replicate the same use case as yours for reference.

```
public class UserAddress
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string UserId {get;set;} 
    public string StreetAddress {get;set;}
}


public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var users = new List<User>();
        users.Add(new User { Id = "1", FirstName = "User1", LastName = "User1"});
        users.Add(new User { Id = "2", FirstName = "User2", LastName = "User2"});
        users.Add(new User { Id = "3", FirstName = "User3", LastName = "User3"});
        users.Add(new User { Id = "4", FirstName = "User4", LastName = "User4"});
        users.Add(new User { Id = "5", FirstName = "User5", LastName = "User5"});

        var addresses  = new List<UserAddress>();

        addresses.Add(new UserAddress{Id = "1", UserId = "1", StreetAddress="Street1" });
        addresses.Add(new UserAddress{Id = "2", UserId = "2", StreetAddress="Street2" });
        addresses.Add(new UserAddress{Id = "3", UserId = "3", StreetAddress="Street3" });
        addresses.Add(new UserAddress{Id = "4", UserId = "4", StreetAddress="Street4" });

        var userId = "1";           
        var q = users.Where(u => u.Id.Equals(userId))
        .Join(addresses, u => u.Id, a => a.UserId, (u,a) => new {u,a}); 

        Console.WriteLine(q);

        var user = users.Where(u => u.Id.Equals(userId))
        .Join(addresses, u => u.Id, a => a.UserId, (u,a) => new {u,a}).Select( x => x.u).FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(user.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(user.FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine(user.LastName);
    }
}
```

I hope this would help you resolve your issue.